# Gradle dependency management to force version

Tags: gradle

What is the best way to do dependency management like in Maven `<dependencyManagement>` tag ?

I did some research online and found out there are a few options:

- Spring gradle dependency management plugin
  https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/1.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/
- Gradle dependency constraints
  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:dependency_constraints
- Gradle configuration resolutionStrategy to force a version

  ```
  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy { 
          force 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
          force 'com.google.guava:guava-gwt:14.0.1'
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Use Gradle's native support for importing BOMs:

From the docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import)

```
dependencies {
    // import a BOM
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.7.RELEASE"))

    // define dependencies without versions
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson")
    implementation("dom4j:dom4j")

    // import a BOM for test dependencies
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.5.1"))

    // define dependency without versions
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}
```

I recommend watching [Managing Dependencies for Spring Projects with Gradle by Jenn Strater and Andy Wilkinson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AADeX1AEmzU) to get some background as to why Spring's dependency management plugin exist and where the plugin itself and Gradle is going.

Comment: Thanks @Francisco, I will take a look

Answer (score 1):

I am using this way to force the version:

```
configurations.all {
        
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'redis.clients') {
                    details.useVersion "3.0.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.jsqlparser') {
                    details.useVersion "2.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.squareup.okhttp3') {
                    details.useVersion "4.0.0"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.pagehelper' && !details.requested.name.contains('spring-boot')) {
                    
                    details.useVersion("5.1.11")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

hope this help for you.